# Python, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to run the below script:

```
i = 0
numbers = []

def number_includer(max_num):        

    while i < max_num:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

number_includer(7)


print "The numbers: "    

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

but when i simply do:

```
numbers = []

def number_includer(max_num):
    # Used i equals 0 inside the function here.
    i = 0

    while i < max_num:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

number_includer(7)


print "The numbers: "    

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

i don't want answer but an explanation, if the problem is with using a local variable inside def which is predefined on the outside, its got no problem with the list 'numbers' being global?

Comment: Add `global i` to the top of `number_includer`.  If you only read a variable from a function, it will look up-level for it if needed, but if you write a variable in a function, it creates a new local variable for it unless it is declared `global` (or also `nonlocal` in Python 3).

Comment: global? isn't using global unorthodox in python?

Comment: I was explaining how to make it do what you intended.  You were clearly trying to access the global copy of `i`.  I told you how.  I never said it was good practice.

Comment: sorry about what i said, thank you for answering.